# Gradle complains about missing jar only during CI job

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab, git-submodules

I'm running a `gradle assemble` on a gitlab job:

```
image: gradle:alpine

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar

after_script:
    - ls -R
```

`gradle assemble` shows no issues and builds fine on my physical machine but on the runner I get the following:

```
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/builds/project/subproject/build/libs/subproject.jar' as it does not exist.
```

Where the subproject is a git submodule.

I expect the project to just build as it does locally, any ideas?

**Edit**

Adding my .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "submodule"]
    path = submodule
    url = https://github.com/thechubbypanda/submodule.git
```

All the files for the submodule exist before the gradle script runs

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run a command to pull all the submodules:

Do this in your `before_script` as well:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Also make sure you have declared the submodules in your `.gitmodules` file.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#git-submodule-strategy

Comment: I've updated my question and the before_script stuff you mentioned is only needed for older versions of Gitlab afaik

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitLab 8.12+ and your submodule is on the same GitLab server, you must update your .gitmodules file to use relative URLs. Since Git allows the usage of relative URLs for your .gitmodules configuration, this easily allows you to use HTTP(S) for cloning all your CI jobs and SSH for all your local checkouts. The .gitmodules would look like:

```
[submodule "project"]
  path = project
  url = ../../group/project.git
```

The complete explanation is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html

try to change your GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY to recursive like the example below

```
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

Comment: As in the .gitmodules, the repo I'm using is on GitHub. Changing the strategy to recursive does nothing.

Comment: sorry my bad, could you paste the submodule output? and are you sure that your github credentials are ok on pipeline?

Comment: the other way to use it is with ssh keys like this article https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

if you will try it, change your submodule to ssh and execute the git submodule commands

Comment: From the output of the ls -R command I can see that all the submodule files are there, that's not the issue. Gradle just doesn't seem to be building the jar for the subproject...